# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when dismissing modalViewController while scrolling tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

I've got a `UITableViewController` that is presented as a modal view. When I do nothing in the modal and use `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` everything works fine. But when I dismiss my modal while scrolling the `UITableView` inside, the application crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

I've already tried NSZombieEnabled but nothing shows up. Somebody knows why my tableview-delegates are still being fired after dismissing the view?

Comment: do u see any messge in console?

Comment: have u given anythng to reload the table?

Comment: before dismiss set nil to table's delegate

Comment: Please go through this link -> http://iphone2020.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/capturing-exceptions-while-debugging/

Comment: - I don't see any message in console, even when I set an 'All Exception' or NSZombieEnabled.

- I don't reload the table in the modal ofter dismissing.

- I already tried setting the tableview and/or the delegate to nil, but no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Check in dealloc method of modalview controller if u r releasing any autoreleased object